# What JSON parsing is simpliest?

Tags: java, json, rest, automated-tests, unirest

For example, I have some REST API testing task. 
I took Unirest framework, and what I have got some JSON extractors,

```
protected int extractStatus (HttpResponse<JsonNode> login) {
    return login.getStatus();
}

protected String extractError (HttpResponse<JsonNode> login) {
    return login.getBody().getObject()
            .getJSONObject("data")
            .getJSONObject("error")
            .toString();
}

protected String extractEmail (HttpResponse<JsonNode> login) {
    return login.getBody().getObject()
            .getJSONObject("data")
            .getJSONObject("result")
            .getJSONObject("userProfile")
            .getString("registrationEmail");
}
```

For my simple tests:

```
public class LoginJSON extends Request {

@Test
public void validLoginTest() {
    response = login("probe@grr.la", "9876541");
    Assert.assertEquals(200, extractStatus(response));
    Assert.assertNotNull("ID expected", extractId(response));
    Assert.assertNotNull("Token expected", extractToken(response));
    Assert.assertEquals("probe@grr.la", extractEmail(response));
    Assert.assertEquals("M", extractGender(response));
    Assert.assertEquals("EmailEnabled", true, extractEmailEnabled(response));
    Assert.assertEquals("EmailDisabled",false, extractEmailDisabled(response));
    Assert.assertEquals(2, extractRolesCount(response));
    Assert.assertTrue("User role expected", extractRoleByName(response, "ROLE_USER"));
    Assert.assertTrue("Admin role expected", extractRoleByName(response, "ROLE_ADMIN"));
}
```

Maybe there was more simpliest way?

Comment: You could use Retrofit w/ a JSON converter

Answer (score 1):

Try [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) with [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)!

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = request.asJson();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String responseJSONString = jsonResponse.getBody().toString();
MyResponseObject myObject = gson.fromJson(responseJSONString, MyResponseObject.class);
```

Classes

```
class MyResponseObject {
  @Serializable("data")
  private MyDataObject myData;
  #get set methods
}

class MyDataObject {
  @Serializable("result")
  private MyResultObject myResultObject;
  #get set methods
}

class MyResultObject {
  @Serializable("userProfile")
  private UserProfileDao userProfileDao;
  #get set methods
}

class UserProfileDao {
  @Serializable("registerationEmail")
  private String registerationEmail;

  #get set methods
}
```

You could do a try catch for successful parse or failed parse.

Comment: But that's is classhell.